# Uncaught Error: Method show does not exist on jQuery.modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So I'm trying to force keep the bootstrap modal showing even on the toggle button click using `$('#myModal').modal('show');`
show method works when outside .click() function but says no such method when it is inside the .click() function

As such

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#my-toggle-button').click(function() {   
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); // Throws up the below error
    });

});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Method show does not exist on jQuery.modal
at Function.error (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.a.fn.modal (materialize.min.js:8)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (myScript.js:4)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
```

However it works fine when

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // Works fine

    $('#my-toggle-button').click(function() {   

    });

});
```

**Update:**
Turns out it's being caused because of script imports having defer and aysnc. I don't know what's the right place to use these as they don't recognize modal.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this error in jsfiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This problem occurs when trying to execute a bootstrap modal when you are also using materializecss, the best recommendation is to use the materializecss modal.

http://materializecss.com/modals.html

```
//initialize all modals
$('.modal').modal({
    dismissible: true
});

//call the specific div (modal)
$('#modal2').modal('open');
```

Enjoy!

Comment: When I remove materialize the error goes away.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using materializecss then just include it before bootstrap like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Then you can use this function to display modal

```
$("#modalId").modal('show');
```

Comment: Not sure how to include that function in the html page.

Comment: <script> $(document).ready(function() { $("#modalId").modal('show'); }) </script>

Answer (score 2):

Please, check the reference to *bootstrap.js* or *bootstrap.min.js* file. The file must include [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) component. Also you need to check identificators of the modal and the button. The code must work fine, see the snippet below.

```js
$('#my-toggle-button').click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="my-toggle-button" class="btn btn-default">Push Me</button>
```